# element tree search help(python, xml)

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to find all child elements whose attribute `class` is 'TRX' and whose attribute `distName` Starts with 'PLMN-PLMN/BSC-208812/BCF-1/BTS-1'

Is something like this possible?

```
root[0].findall("*[@class='TRX'][@distName='PLMN-PLMN/BSC-208812/BCF-1/BTS-1*']")
```

I'm using cElementTree over lxml because it is much much faster on my comp.

Answer (score 2):

ElementTree can in fact do this.

You may need to use `.//*` instead of `*`.

[Python docs ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) version 1.3.0 which comes with Python 2.7 has the XPath capabilities you seek.

**Example**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

et = ElementTree.fromstring("""
<r>
    <b>
        <a class='c' foo='e'>this is e</a>
        <a class='c' foo='f'>this is f</a>
        <a class='c' foo='g'>this is g</a>
    </b>
</r>
""")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ElementTree.VERSION
    print  "* c and f", et.findall("*[@class='c'][@foo='f']")
    print  ".//* c and f", et.findall(".//*[@class='c'][@foo='f']")
    print  ".//* c", et.findall(".//*[@class='c']")
    print  ".//* f", et.findall(".//*[@foo='f']")
```

**Output**

```
1.3.0
* c and f []
.//* c and f [<Element 'a' at 0x10049be50>]
.//* c [<Element 'a' at 0x10049bdd0>, <Element 'a' at 0x10049be50>, <Element 'a' at 0x10049bf10>]
.//* f [<Element 'a' at 0x10049be50>]
```

Comment: I guess I misphrased my question, I want to find all class = 'c' whose
foo attribute begins with something

Comment: My bad, I didn't read it.  http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm shows that it doesn't support starts-with(), which is what you need for that.

Comment: I did it by iterating the loop in python... It's still faster than lxml because of the structure of the xml...